# Hide gutenberg option blocks

Tags: hooks, block-editor

How to Hide/disable every feature on the New Post creator,

Just the following area visible:

- Gutenberg Editor
- Publish button
- Tags
- Categories

Even hiding the left sidebar and all menu options too.

Comment: Are you wanting to fully disable Gutenberg or just want to get it to a "blank" slate for your own custom blocks?

Comment: I just want a very clean environment for my author to write, with no bloat or extra setting he/she can mess up with. I feel a lot of settings not usually exposed to author or contributor level in WP are available for them in Gutenberg.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the panels related to the entire post (e.g. the featured image, excerpt)
can be removed and
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/17281 shows how.

e.g.

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'featured-image' );
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post').removeEditorPanel( 'post-excerpt' );
```

The sidebar is also used for additional block options and [there's currently no cohesive, consistent way to manage whether a block's options](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/20588) are available to your editors.